# How is Novel different from Novella, other than Word Count

Tags: novel, novella

How is a Novel different from Novella, other than word count?

Is Novel supposed to provide description of background, i.e. background noises, color of the sky, etc before showing character dialogue.

Can you clarify.

Comment: A novel is not just a novelette with padded descriptions of the landscape. A novel has literally *more story*. This podcast discusses a formula for estimating story length, and also publishing standards.
 https://writingexcuses.com/2017/07/02/12-27-choosing-a-length/

Answer (score 4):

### There are no strict differences between a novel and a novella besides word count.

As a matter of necessity, because a novella has fewer words than a novel, there will be less of *something*, but it is only fewer words that makes something not a novel.  Some novellas will have less dialogue, some will have sparser descriptions or fewer side-characters; some just fewer plot points before the finale.  The difference between a novel and novella could even be that the novella is simply less unnecessarily wordy.

**Besides length, there are no hard and fast technical differences.**

For that matter, there are no set rules on how much description or dialogue or how many plot points are required to "correctly" write a novel.  If you have told your story in a way that best serves the story and your writing style and your intended audience, it is correct.  If, say, you have too little description or too many side-characters, fix it in the second draft.  Then, when you're finished polishing, if your story is long enough, it's a novel; if it's short enough, it's a short story.  If it's in that awkward middle place, it's a novella.